# How does arena category work on Marvel Contest of Champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

Recently I got a Magneto Marvel Now on a 3* arena. With a 400k score I got top 10% reward. A member of my alliance got 600k score and was placed top 60%. So he told me that there is a "bracket system" where players are divided in three categories: rookie, intermediate and veteran.

- Are there only 3 categories? Rookie, intermediate and veteran?
- How do I find out what my category is?
- When do players move from one category to the next one?
- Are the ranked rewards base score the same for all categories? For example, for me it is 20k for 3* arenas and 150k for 4* arenas.

I know it is not a good idea to post many questions, but they are completely related and if someone knows the answer for one, they must know the answer for all of them (I guess :P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 brackets:

1) Beginner: if you have played for less than 1 month.

2) Intermediate: 60 days.

3) Veteran: 61+ days.

You can tell mostly by looking at the rank rewards in the prizes section of the arena.

Beginner 4* arena: top 50 get 4* featured.

Intermediate 4*: top 100 get 4* featured.

Veteran 4*: top 400 get 4* featured.

Info found here:

http://community.kabam.com/forums/showthread.php?522083-What-are-brackets&highlight=arena+bracket

http://community.kabam.com/forums/showthread.php?519876-Arena-Feedback-Cross-post&p=2556152&viewfull=1#post2556152